# Parsing response string to xml with jdom2

Tags: java, xml, string, jdom-2

I want to parse my `StringBuffer` with `Jdom2` after a `SOAP` call. But I didn't find a solution anywhere.

I saw a few solutions with `w3.jdom`, but they asked me to do with `jdom2`.

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

String line = "";

while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder` and use its `build(Reader)` method to create a JDOM2 `Document` object, where the Reader is created using `new StringReader(result.toString())`.

However, copying all the data out of an HTTP response into a StringBuffer just so that you can then parse it is pretty inefficient. You're already getting an InputStream from the `HttpResponse` using `response.getEntity().getContent()`, and you can supply this `InputStream` directly to the SAXBuilder's `build(InputStream)` method.